# Any sort of real world application for volumes of solids (revolution)$?$

Tags: calculus, volume

Just wondering if you've ever encountered an actual situation that  is  related to the concept of integration of cross sectional area to find $3d$ volume.

Comment: I am looking at a bottle of water on my desk at the moment. It is perfectly rotationally symmetrical around a central axis. I am sure some manufacturer had to design it so that it had a certain volume...

Comment: I think there are plenty of applications in mechanical engineering. I am thinking of pressure vessels, hydrodynamics, engines, because there both the volume and the shape of the enclosure are important.

Comment: [Do I have enough snow to build a snowman?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080130154813AA3kKPY)

Comment: It reminds me of [MRI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging). It's not a solid of revolution deal, but absolutely understanding a three dimensional volume via cross sections.

Comment: Interesting, the water bottles generally have a whole number for the volume, so the shape is deliberate.

Comment: What is the principle behind MRI ?